# AngularJS ui-router resolve not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with my resolve into my ui router state.

The template is rendered before the resolve and I can't figure why.

Here are the states :

```
 .state({
            name: 'common.list',
            url: '/lists/list/:id',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/lists/crud/crud.html',
            controller: 'ListsCrudController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                label: '{{ vm.title }}',
                parent: 'common.lists'
            }
        })
        .state({
            name: 'common.list.new',
            url: '/new',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/lists/crud/crudForm.html',
            resolve: {
                entityMetadata: function ($http, $stateParams) {                        
                    return $http.get('//localhost/IRE.Scanning.Services/api/FormMetadata/' + $stateParams.id + 'DefaultForm')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response.data;
                        });
                }
            },
            controller: 'ListsCrudFormController',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                label: 'Nouveau'
            }

        });
```

The controller :

```
class ListsCrudFormController {       
    entityMetadata: any;
    constructor(entityMetadata: any) {
        this.entityMetadata = entityMetadata;

    }
```

Do anyone have an idea about my issue?

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to add the resolve data as a dependency to your controller as well.

Comment: @AbdulMannan Look at the line `constructor(entityMetadata: any) {`

Comment: @AbdulMannan It's already set as a dependency